# Keep text in UITextView highlighted when the popover is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, highlight, uipopover

I have a UIPopover that shows up a plain view containing a UITextView filled with some text. I have managed to highlight the text. When the popover is dismissed, and re-opened, the highlight disappears. I want to keep the text highlighted even if if the application is closed. Any ideas how to achieve that?
The code i used is the following :

```
    - (void)highlight {

         NSRange selectedRange = self.textViewAll.selectedRange;

         NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                                        initWithAttributedString:self.textViewAll.attributedText];

         [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                  value:[UIColor redColor]
                                  range:selectedRange];

       //  [highlightedRange addObject:];
// This is where i tried to save each location and length in a mutable array but didn't work
         [highlightedRangeLocation insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:selectedRange.location] atIndex:indexOfHighlight];
         [highlightedRangeLength insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:selectedRange.length] atIndex:indexOfHighlight];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         self.textViewAll.attributedText = attributedString;

         indexOfHighlight ++ ;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
         UIMenuItem *highlightMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Highlight" action:@selector(highlight)];
         [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highlightMenuItem]];

         float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

         if (sysVer >= 8.0) {
              self.textViewAll.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
         }


         }
```

Could anyone point out how to continue from here?

**Edit 1 :**

The code that close the popover :

```
- (IBAction)closeFun:(id)sender {

  //   self.popoverPresentationController set

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // [self dismis]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you juste save the Highlighted text range in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] whenever the popover is dismissed, and retrieve it when the popover reappears ?

Comment: this was the best approach :) the most convenient one...congrats on the bounty !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the fact that the popover is responsible for the highlighted state, i.e .it is the popover who keeps that fact/state.
The popover is a part of presentation layer / user interface. Surely the highlight represents some fact that ( now comes the catch ) - **is completely independent of the popover.**

For example highlighting a task could represent that the task is due. Or, highlighting a label to red color could mean that the balance in the bank is in negative numbers.
You see, no matter what user interface element you use, they only represent some underlying business reality. 
But what probably happens you create a popover instance, you set it to have a highlighted element. But then this **concrete popover instance dies**, when it is closed.

> **And the highlight dies with it.**

When you click some button (I guess), a popover shows up, but it is a **different instance.**  This instance doesn't know about highlight.
Even if you somehow managed to keep the one instance of popover alive, and just hide and show it again, the popover should NOT be responsible to know whether something is red or due, (and thus highlighted.)

In you application, you should have a **well separated model layer**...which is basically a set of related objects that represent state ie. fact that are related to what the application solves from business perspective (for ex. draws lines, calculates interest..stores music..anything really).  This model layer, some object in it, should store the facts..ie.e. the task is due, or the balance is low.

Every time you show your popover, you should investigate **what are the underlying facts in your model layer** right when the popover is being shown. Ivestigating means find a programmatic way to look into model objects, find out about values there and and set up the highlight in that moment again based on this "investigation". You should not rely on the fact that it was highlighted in the not so distant past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and you are absolutely right.. but since i am facing this problem right now i need to find any solution in terms of actually getting it to work ! could you please guide me to a tutorial or any code snippet that could actually help me learn and navigate me to the right place?

Comment: Well in this case make a private popover property in interface class extension, implement the getter for that property explicitly, lazily initialising the popover, and just show and hide it. Since you will be showing and hiding the same instance over and over, it will keep its state ie anything inside will stay highlighted.

Comment: i need a code changing solution...if you could help me out i would assure you would get the bounty...i would highly appreciate it..it's been a nightmare for the past couple of days!

Comment: Can you show me the part of code that does the highlighting?

Comment: This is not doing any highlighting of text..this is purely dismissing a presented view controller.

Comment: sorry i mis-read! the code responsible of the highlighting is included in the original question ! i add a button "Highlight" in the viewDidLoad that calls the function -(void)highlight that actually does the highlight

Comment: Sorry my mistake ,i was blind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72151/discussion-between-earl-grey-and-elias-rahme).